# What page I must edit for changing text in WP /profile page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 2 pages, /profile and /tarifs in WordPress site.
What PHP script pages should I edit for changing text there?
I have Filezilla and access for server. Or it can be done in admin?

Comment: I think you are better off on the [wordpress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) site for this friend :P

Comment: I second @Sam Swift... But yes, you should change them via the WP Admin if the site is setup correctly and those are infact Pages / Posts

Answer (score 0):

in your current active theme .

```
author.php
```

if it not exesit add new one and cutomize it .

```
 <?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="content" class="narrowcolumn">
<!– This sets the $curauth variable –>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['author_name'])) :
$curauth = get_userdatabylogin($author_name);
else :
$curauth = get_userdata(intval($author));
endif;
?>
<h2>About: <?php echo $curauth->nickname; ?></h2>
<dl>
<dt>Website</dt>
<dd><a href="<?php echo $curauth->user_url; ?>"><?php echo $curauth->user_url; ?></a></dd>
<dt>Profile</dt>
<dd><?php echo $curauth->user_description; ?></dd>
</dl>
<h2>Posts by <?php echo $curauth->nickname; ?>:</h2>
<ul>
<!– The Loop –>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<li>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link: <?php the_title(); ?>">
<?php the_title(); ?></a>,
<?php the_time('d M Y'); ?> in <?php the_category('&');?>
</li>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('No posts by this author.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<!– End Loop –>
</ul>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

[Ref](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-a-custom-author-profile-page-to-your-wordpress/)